# \n is not showing newline in chatter feed

Tags: chatter

I am modifying the chatter feed on a after insert trigger on FeedItem object.

Code:

```
ConnectApi.FeedItem item = (ConnectApi.FeedItem) theResult;   
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = ConnectApiHelper.createFeedItemInputFromBody(item.body);

ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textInput3 = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textInput3.text = '\n\n---\nDisclaimer: Modified in a trigger.';
input.body.messageSegments.add(textInput3);

ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.updateFeedElement(commID, item.id, input);
```

Until yesterday it was showing text in new line. But since today morning it is appending the additional text in single line i.e. \n are truncated.

Can anyone help me how to show it in new line?

Note: I have tried `'<'br'/>'` and `'\r\n'` approaches. They are not working.

Edit:

```
public class ConnectApiHelper {

public static ConnectApi.FeedItemInput createFeedItemInputFromBody(ConnectApi.FeedBody body) {
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput bodyInput = createInputFromBody(body);
    ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
    input.body = bodyInput;
    return input;
}

public static ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput createInputFromBody(ConnectApi.FeedBody body) {
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput input = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
    input.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

    for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment segment : body.messageSegments) {
        if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.TextSegment) {
            ConnectApi.TextSegment textOutput = (ConnectApi.TextSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
            textInput.text = textOutput.text;
            input.messageSegments.add(textInput);
        }
        else if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment) {
            ConnectApi.MentionSegment mentionOutput = (ConnectApi.MentionSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
            mentionInput.id = mentionOutput.record.id;
            input.messageSegments.add(mentionInput);
        }
        else if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.HashtagSegment) {
            ConnectApi.HashtagSegment hashtagOutput = (ConnectApi.HashtagSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.HashtagSegmentInput hashtagInput = new ConnectApi.HashtagSegmentInput();
            hashtagInput.tag = hashtagOutput.tag;
            input.messageSegments.add(hashtagInput);
        }
        else if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.LinkSegment) {
            ConnectApi.LinkSegment linkOutput = (ConnectApi.LinkSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.LinkSegmentInput linkInput = new ConnectApi.LinkSegmentInput();
            linkInput.url = linkOutput.url;
            input.messageSegments.add(linkInput);
        }
        else if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegment) {
            ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegment markupBeginOutput = (ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput markupBeginInput = new ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput();
            markupBeginInput.markupType = markupBeginOutput.markupType;
            input.messageSegments.add(markupBeginInput);
        }
        else if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegment) {
            ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegment markupEndOutput = (ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput markupEndInput = new ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput();
            markupEndInput.markupType = markupEndOutput.markupType;
            input.messageSegments.add(markupEndInput);
        }
        else if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.InlineImageSegment) {
            ConnectApi.InlineImageSegment inlineImageOutput = (ConnectApi.InlineImageSegment) segment;
            ConnectApi.InlineImageSegmentInput inlineImageInput = new ConnectApi.InlineImageSegmentInput();
            inlineImageInput.fileId = inlineImageOutput.thumbnails.fileId;
            inlineImageInput.altText = inlineImageOutput.altText;
            input.messageSegments.add(inlineImageInput);
        }
        else {
            // The other segment types are system-generated and have no corresponding input types.
        }

    }
    System.debug(input.messageSegments);
    return input;
}
```

}

When I enable ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegment and ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegment then only I am not getting \n as new line. IF i comment those two if checks I am getting new line feed.

Comment: try `\\\n`. it might help.

Comment: \\\n is also not working. @TusharSharma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the Rich Text feature that was introduced in v35.0 of the API. As you saw, if there are no markup segments, the post is treated as plain-text and the newlines are preserved. If there are markup segments, you need to do the following to achieve a newline:

- Create a `ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput` of type Paragraph
- Create a `ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput` with text = '& nbsp;'  (with no space between the & and n -- I had to add a space in order to get it to display properly here)
- Create a `ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput` of type Paragraph

In your example, you'd want to put the three segments inputs before and after `textInput3` in the list of `input.body.messageSegments` to see some newlines.

It's the Apex equivalent of this [REST example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_element_rich_text.htm).

Other options are:

- Compile the triggers using API v34.0 (I haven't tried this, but I think it will work since the rich text feature was introduced in v35.0). You'll have to make sure you use the [appropriate version of ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper/tree/master/v32-v34).
- Disable the rich text feature in your org.

Comment: Thanks @alouie. I have already commit the code using the first approach you have mentioned and it is working fine. I didn't post my ans to know any other approach to the same. Thanks for the confirmation and I ll sure check the other two approaches you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same as you - modifying Chatter post in After Insert Trigger.  I had a similar issue where there were newlines in the original feedItem.body, but after I updated the message, the newlines in the original text were gone.

I got around this by modifying the ConnectApiHelper.createInputFromBody code as such:

```
    //identify newline and replace it with encoded values that MessageSegment will handle correctly
    string newline = EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%0A', 'UTF-8'); 

    for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment segment : body.messageSegments) {
        if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.TextSegment) {
            ConnectApi.TextSegment textOutput = (ConnectApi.TextSegment) segment;
            if (textOutput.text.indexOf(newline) > -1) {
                //if newline is found create multiple message segments instead of just a textSegment
                List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput> newSegments = 
                        ConnectApiHelper.getMessageSegmentInputs(textOutput.text
                                                                    .replaceAll(newline+newline,'<p>&nbsp;</p>')
                                                                    .replaceAll(newline,'<p></p>'));
                input.messageSegments.addAll(newSegments);
            } else {
                ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
                textInput.text = textOutput.text;
                input.messageSegments.add(textInput);
            }
        } 

        ...
```

When newlines are encountered, I replace them with `<p></p>` tags and let ConnectApiHelper code create the multiple messageSegments for this instead of a single textSegment. 
Saves a lot of headache of creating all the segments manually.

BTW - I submitted a pull request for this today to get it included in ConnectApiHelper: https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper/pull/16

Answer (score 0):

I have found in lightning String.fromCharCode(13) works to create line breaks but not in classic but if you use "\n" it will work in both at least as of the time of this post. For JavaScript at the least hope this helps somone